# Receive Spring ResponseEntity with and without body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

### How to implement a REST call which can sometimes return no body?

My SpringBoot application calls an external service over REST HTTP and its implemented via the `org.springframework.web.client` Client and method `public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange`.

The client received till now always a String body -> `ResponseEntity<String>`. Some time ago the service we are calling returns us HTTP 202 **without body**, so the following exception is thrown:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "content" is null`.

**How can I tell Spring to ignore the body for a 202 status code?**

Comment: handle it with your custom exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Void](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Void.html) as the generic type parameter for [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) if the service does not return a response body:

```
ResponseEntity<Void> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Void.class)
```

If the service returns a response sometimes, you could handle the response as a `String`. For empty responses, you would receive an empty string. For non-empty responses, you would need to deserialize the returned payload yourself.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class)
if (Strings.isEmpty(res.getBody())) {
    // handle empty response
} else {
    // handle non-empty response
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. Unfortenutelly it doesnt suit the problem, because the service *does* return a response, but no body - sometimes.